# Do guards ever take any action against you for shouting in cities?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Do the guards just keep asking you to stop, or do they eventually charge you a fine or something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do not use harmful shouts in towns against guards.

Non-Harmful shouts, you get a warning. Harmful shouts you get a bounty if used and a town guard was in the affected area, or a person was in the area a guard was happening by.

Tested all of the below.

If you hit a guard or a citizen, the below will make them hostile:

- Unrelenting Force
- Fire Breath
- Frost Breath
- Ice Form
- Marked for Death
- Storm Call

Comment: I first tested storm call in a city, thinking it'd be like clear skies and simply change the weather. You can imagine my surprise when I see a thousand red dots appear on the compass.

Comment: Non-harmful shouts only ever get warnings, so shout away, lie to the guard that you'll stop, and shout some more.

Comment: My first experience with Storm Call was pretty much same as @Reid.  I've sworn to never use it again since.  Call Dragon makes for an awesome substitute.

Comment: You'll change your mind at higher difficulties. Storm call destroys while call dragon and followers are nearly useless.

Answer (score 10):

As far as my experience goes. I Have never been fined or anything personally - dont know if thats possible. But obviously if you do a shout that hurts anyone, there guards will attack etc.

I use shouts in towns to get the 'Friend' letters that give you locations which lead to a 'word' wall.

Only ever been asked to stop shouting as it makes the residents nervous.

Answer (score 4):

No, you'll never get a bounty just for shouting into the air, unless your shout actually hits someone and causes harm.

Alternately, you can end up with a bounty if a guard runs up to warn you about how shouting makes the townsfolk nervous, and you proceed to mouth off to the guard. Don't do that.

Comment: I did mouth off to the guard and he gave me a warning and walked away, didn't fine me.

Comment: I don't remember the exact set of dialog options, but I've been slapped with a 10 gold bounty by disrespecting a guard once. Might be hold specific. They do play a bit more fast and loose with the rules in some parts.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. You get told off mainly if you knock something over in town and a bounty for accidentally hitting them. If you want to hurt people without being prosecuted, go to Dragonsreach and Unrelenting Force the dining table, the sheer joy of watching 50 pots and pans fly at a guard is just amazing if he actually gets hit (which should happen 3 times if you did it right). He will stroll over and tell you to stop. :D